# Does move constructor change the memory to which "this" points to?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I have some confusions about C++ move constructor. If the compiler is implicitly synthesizing a move constructor, what will this move constructor do? Will it just make "this" point to the object that is used for initialization?
there's an example:

```
struct Foo {
    int i;
    int *ptr;
};

Foo x;
Foo y(std::move(x));
```

will the implicitly synthesized move constructor just make `this` in `y` point to the memory that `x` is in? If so, how to ensure that `x` is destructible after the move (if `x` is destroyed, will members in `y` be valid)? if not, how does the move constructor of `y` work?

Comment: 1. No, and 2. how move ctors work (vs how copy-ctors work) is covered at length in a multitude of questions on this site. [this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378721/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-constructor-and-move-constructor-in-c). And [especially this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the implicitly *synthesized move constructor* just make this in y point to the memory that x is in?

The **synthesized move ctor** will ***memberwise-move*** the data members of its arguments(`x` here) to the object being created(`y` here).

Also, note that for built-in types like `int`, move is the same as copying.

---

> how to ensure that x is destructible after the move

Since move is the same as copying for built in types, `x` and `y` are independent of each other. So when `x` is destroyed `y` will not be affected.

---

> will the synthesized move constructor set the `ptr` of `x` to `nullptr`?

No, the synthesize move ctor will not do that for you. It will just memberwise move the data members. For built in types this means the same as copying.

---

> if it does not do this, then the `ptr` of `x` will still point to the memory to which the `ptr` of `y` points, then you cannot safely destroy `x`.

In that case, you'd need to write a **user-defined move ctor** which explicitly sets the `ptr` of `x` to `nullptr` so that when `x` is destroyed, the `y` is not affected.

Comment: how the move constructor moves the int or string type members? Will it just copy the values of these members to the initialized class object?

Comment: And, will the synthesized move constructor set the ```ptr``` of ```x``` to ```nullptr```? if it does not do this, then the ```ptr```of ```x``` will still point to the memory to which the ```ptr``` of ```y``` points, then you cannot safely destroy ```x```.

Comment: @kaiyuwei For built-in types like `int`, `move` is the same as copying. More can be found [here:Do built-in types have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679605/do-built-in-types-have-move-semantics). That is, for built in types a `move` is a copy.

Comment: @kaiyuwei No, the synthesized move ctor will not set the `ptr` of `x` to `nullptr`. It will just memberwise move the data members from `x` to `y` without doing anything else. Also note that for built in type data members like `int`, move is the same as copying. So `x` and `y` are independent of each other. If both the pointers of `x` and `y` point to the same memory, the you'll need to write your own move constructor that will set `x` to nullptr. The synthesized ctor will not do that for you.

Comment: @kaiyuwei You'd have to write a user-defined move ctor which explicitly sets the `ptr` of `x` to `nullptr` so that when `x` is destroyed, the `y` is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

> will the implicitly synthesized move constructor just make this in y point to the memory that x is in?

As Anoop noted, it will memberwise call the move constructor on every member of the source to be moved (`x`) onto the members of the destination (`y` or `this` if you imagine yourself "inside" that synthesized move constructor).

So in your example:

- the `int` `x.i` will be moved onto `y.i` (`this->i`)
- the `int*` `x.ptr` will be moved onto `y.ptr` (`this->ptr`).

Note that these particular moves will be performed by copying.

> how to ensure that x is destructible after the move (if x is destroyed, will members in y be valid)?

It's always destructible.  As to if it's "valid", it depends. The default move construction was actually a copy.  Two objects now point at whatever `x.ptr` pointed to.  If that `int` was a resource "owned" by `x` (maybe the resource was a 0 terminated string of ints on the heap), then you've just "shared" that resource.

If you don't wish to "share" it then you could have explicitly written a move constructor for `Foo` that resets the pointer of the "moved-from" object, or somehow marks it invalid.

```cpp
struct Foo {
  ...
  Foo(Foo&& other) {
    this->i = other.i;
    this->ptr = other.ptr;
    other.ptr = nullptr;
  }
}
```

In general, it's best not to rely on "moved from" objects at all, i.e. make sure they are destroyed as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks Joao, since the ```x.ptr``` and ```y.ptr``` are pointing to the same object, how can you say that ```x``` is destructible? since if you destroy ```x``` then the object to which ```y.ptr``` points will also be destroyed, which makes ```y.ptr''' invalid.

Comment: Right, but in the example you first posted, there was no such destructor of the `ptr` member! So the thing that `ptr` points to would *not* be destroyed. If there _were_ such a destructor, then that destructor should probably check if `ptr` is `nullptr` and not destroy it. And that is a good reason to define the move constructor as I suggested.

Comment: Clear enough to me now. Thanks a lot!